# Angular Route [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm trying angular Routes

I have 3 files:

1. apps
2. bearCtrl
3. bearRoute

-apps:

```
var bearApp = angular.module('bearApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

-bearCtrl

```
bearApp.controller('bearCtrl',['$scope',function ($scope) {
$scope.bears = [
    {
        name:'Bear1'
        ,price:25
    },
    {
        name:'Bear2'
        ,price:30
    }
];
}]);
```

-bearRoute

```
bearApp.config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/template1.html', 
      controller: ''
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

In my html I have a `<div ng-view></div>`

I'm getting this error, I wonder what I'm doing wrong:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: It sounds like you didn't include the `ngRoute` script file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to add angular-route.js (or its minified version) in the list of JS files loaded by your page:

```
<script src="/js/angular-route.js"></script>
```

The ngRoute module is a separate module that needs to be downloaded and used in addition to angular.
See http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/

Comment: I did not know that routes was a separate script.

T.y++